# Angular / grunt failed to load template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I recently introduced angular directives into my yeoman app for templating, and everything works fine if I grunt serve the normal dev version of the app, but when I build the 'dist' folder with grunt and serve it, the html in the directives of my app don't appear on the page and the console logs this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

vendor.6e8f248d.js:5 Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: 
/views/tabdir.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)
```

I read that dependency injection needs to be in an array format so that minification doesn't mess with it, and so I did this for all of my controllers, but the same problem still persists. Eg:

```
angular.module('MainApp').controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'inputBlur', function ($scope, inputBlur) {

}]);
```

What is causing my directives to not be loaded correctly by grunt?

Comment: It sounds like your build process with Grunt isn't quite configured correctly. Are you using `html2js` to include the HTML templates in dev correctly, but not concatenating them to your dist scripts, perhaps? What are the differences between the way the HTML files are delivered in dev vs dist? I'm pretty sure it's nothing to do with minification errors.

Comment: I haven't heard of html2js and I'm using default settings configured by yeoman. Would this help me? And what sort of differences between the dev/dist should I be looking for?

Comment: I don't know what the default settings yeoman uses are, sorry. One thing you can check is whether requests are made for the HTML templates when running in dev mode (use the Network tab of developer tools). Also check if the list of JS files served (or the content of them) is the same between dev and dist.

Comment: The dev/dist network tabs are different in that the dev isn't minified while the dist is. The network tab for the dist shows failed GET requests for the unminified html directives as if it's trying to grab the unminified files that are no longer there. Could this be the problem?

Comment: It really does sound like the dev JS files contain the HTML templates as JS. Search for `$templateCache.put(` in the dev and dist files - if I'm right, a whole bunch of them will be in the dev files but not the dist files. Alternatively, if it is actually fetching the HTML partials from the server in dev mode, then you probably need to look into using something like `html2js` to include the partials in the dist JS files so you don't have to distribute the HTML files separately.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue. Remove the first foreslash `/` in the `templateUrl` value of your directive, should be like this:

```
templateUrl:'views/tabdir.html'
```

Comment: Worked for me so check your templateURL