# grunt build failed to load template

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I created a yeoman angular project that is not building properly. After I run run the production build (dist folder), I get this error:

> Failed to load template: /bundles/craigslist/main.html

It seems to be copying the files, but since the html files get turned into a string that lives in dist/scripts.js, it throws an error when trying to find /bundles/craigslist/main.html

**In my "/dist/scripts.js":**

```
.config(["$routeProvider", function(a) { 
      a.when("/", {
           templateUrl:"/bundles/craigslist/main.html",
           controller:"CraigslistMainCtrl",
           controllerAs:"craigslist_main_root"
      })
```

**Info if necessary:**

instead of the pattern /scripts  and /views,  I use bundles that organize similar files together, regardless of extension. For example, I have a /bundles/craigslist folder, which has the craigslist templates, service and routes.  I'm trying to adjust my Gruntfile.js to account for this.

This is my grunt file: https://gist.github.com/ivansifrim/f632832a4ba8f44bf828b5d88066a0ce

This is my folder structure:

[image: This is my folder structure]

I tried to apply what was discussed here [Angular / grunt failed to load template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35399087/angular-grunt-failed-to-load-template) without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
usemin: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/**/*.html'],
  css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
  js: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/bundles/{,*/}*.js'],
  options: {
    assetsDirs: [
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles'
    ],
    patterns: {
      js: [[/(images\/[^''""]*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp|svg))/g, 'Replacing references to images']]
    }
  }
}
```